# Complex Function: Radius of convergence and convolutions.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, analytic-functions

Let $R>0$ be the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^{n}$, then what is the radii of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{2}_{n}z^{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_nz^{n-1}$?

> We'll do the easy one first.
>
> we know that for an analytic function $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ with >radius of convergence R then $\exists$ a function $f'(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n >a_n z^{n-1}$
>
> Comparing the two functions $g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_n z^{n-1}$ and $f'(z)$ >we have
>   $$\lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty}|f'(z)-g(z)| = \lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty} >|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n a_n z^{n-1} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_n z^{n-1}|$$
>   $$\lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty} |0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_n z^{n-1} - >\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_n z^{n-1}| = 0~\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$
>   $$\implies$$
>   $$g(z) = f'(z)$$ and so $g(z)$ has Radius of convergence R, the same as $f(z)$
>
> now the slightly more interesting one.
>   define $h(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{2}_{n}z^{n}$ which we can clearly define to >be a cauchy product and so $h(z)$ is just the convolution of $f(z)^2$
>   since via abel's lemma: 
>   $$\text{if }~\{a_n\} \subset \mathbb{C} \text{ and }\sum a_n \text{ converge, then >} \lim_{x \longrightarrow 1^{-}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} >a_n$$
>
> and the convolution lemma:
>
> If the complex series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge absolutely, then so does >their convolution $c_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ib_{n-i}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n = >\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$
>
> applying these two lemmas we have
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^2_{n} = \lim _{n \longrightarrow 1^{-}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^{2}_{n}z^{n} = \lim _{n \longrightarrow 1^{-}} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}\right) = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\right) = f(z)f(z)$$
>   and so we can say that the radius of convergence of $h(z)$ is $\overline{R} \geq \min\{R,R\} \implies \overline{R} \geq R$
>
> we know that $$\frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{n \longrightarrow \infty} |a_{n}|^{1/n}$$
>   letting $h_n$ be the co-coefficients of $h(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} h_{n}z^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{2}_{n}z^{n}$
>
> then $$\limsup_{n \longrightarrow \infty}|h_{n}|^{1/n} = \limsup_{n \longrightarrow \infty}|a_{n}^{2}|^{1/n}= \limsup_{n \longrightarrow \infty}>(|a_{n}||a_n|)^{1/n}$$
>   for $a_n = u(x,y)+iv(x,y), |a_n| \in \mathbb{R}$
>   $$\limsup_{n \longrightarrow \infty}(|a_{n}||a_n|)^{1/n} = \limsup_{n \longrightarrow \infty}(|a_{n}|^{1/n}|a_n|^{1/n}) = (\limsup_{n \longrightarrow \infty}|a_{n}|^{1/n})(\limsup_{n \longrightarrow \infty}|a_{n}|^{1/n}) = \frac{1}{R^2}$$ Which is fine given that it is not of the form $0 \cdot \infty$ and we note that
>   $$\overline{R} = R^{2} \geq R$$
>
> so for $h(z)$ we find by squaring the co-coefficients of the power series we have >also squared the radius of convergence.<\strike>
>
> Have i gone wrong anywhere?
>   Thanks for taking the time to read this.
>   Sincerely

**The above answer is Wrong, Please see my second attempt at** [Complex Function: Radius of convergence Pt 2: Complex Boogaloo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3424348/complex-function-radius-of-convergence-pt-2-complex-boogaloo)

Comment: Third line from the bottom you should have $\frac 1 {R{2}}$ instead of $R^{2}$.

Comment: ah cheers for that. i didn't notice it.

Comment: Everything is wrong. In the first case you have limits in $n$ of functions that don't depend on $n$ and which are not related to computing the radius of convergence required. In the second case the series in question is not $f^2(x)$.

Comment: with regards to everything being wrong, even if the originally assumptions are wrong, what about the calculation of $\frac{1}{R^2}$? ie the bottom paragraph? from "we know that" to "which is fine given that is it not of the form $0 \cdot \infty$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have gone wrong, yes.

In the case of the first series, what do you mean by $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl\lvert f'(z)-g(z)\bigr\rvert$? There is no $n$ in $\bigl\lvert f'(z)-g(z)\bigr\rvert$ and therefore, for each $z\in\mathbb C$, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl\lvert f'(z)-g(z)\bigr\rvert=\bigl\lvert f'(z)-g(z)\bigr\rvert$.

You can prove that both series have the same redius of convergence by proving that$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\lvert a_n\rvert}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n\lvert a_{n-1}\rvert}.$$

Concerining your other problem, it is **not** true that$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n\implies f^2(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a_n}^2z^n.$$For instance,$$\frac1{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty1\times z^n\text{ but }\frac1{1-z^2}\neq\sum_{n=0}^\infty1^2z^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n.$$In order to solve this problem, you can use again the $\limsup$ approach.

Comment: we already have it in the notes that in the first series, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_n z^{n-1} = f'(z)$ and has the same radius of convergence, which is why i was going along the route of showing that  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_n z^{n-1} = f'(z) = 0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_n z^n$ and showing they're the same function, otherwise i'd be rehashing the notes... none the less, i'll rewrite everything up and then re-post afterwards, Thanks for the answer thus far.

Comment: Does that mean that you are going to turn your question into another question for which my answer is not an answer anymore?

Comment: no, i somewhat plan on editing the above question giving another answer, whilst leaving the wrong working out still there, then reanswering and giving you the option to say "yes that's right" or "no thats still wrong" in which case i'd then carry on untill it's right...your answer would still stand and you've still had the upvote. 
it will be the same question.
Would you suggest i close it entirely and start again?
otherwise others who would make the same mistake as me wouldn't see the progression in thought..

Comment: Since it is (in principle) another approach, yes, I think that it should be another question.

Comment: This will be my last comment then and will then accept the answer and redirect from here later. But although i agree in principle it's another approach i would also argue that it is still the same question and we ask questions rather than simply post approaches. None the less, this is a question for Meta i imagine. before i go, would you be kind enough to tell me whether my calculation of $\frac{1}{R^2}$ is correct or should i recalculate the $\limsup h(z)$ i accept that $h(z)$ is not equal to $f^{2}(z)$ but no one has really mentioned whether that calculation is correct or not.

Comment: It seems that you are assuming that, if you have two sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, then $\limsup_n(a_nb_n)=\left(\limsup_na_n\right)\left(\limsup_nb_n\right)$. If that is so, then you are wrong.